# IPtables client - server(router) error

Tags: networking, server, internet, vmware, iptables

I've got a school assessment this week.

Let me explain how my environment is:

1 Router (Have DHCP + giving an ip to the client) Has NAT for Internet 
1 Client (Can only have internet acccess via the router) Has HOST-ONLY

My problem: IPTABLES

I've got a couple of rules that i've found on the internet. But none of all are working.
Example: http://pastebin.com/uKH2rHue

Is this even possible? because it did not work at mine.

MY question: How can I configure IPTABLES router for redirecting or forwarding the incoming traffic to INTERNET? (HTTP REQUEST by having internet ACCESS)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does your question relate with your school assessment? Also, what kind of traffic do you try to redirect? Do have a server on your LAN that needs to be accessibly to the internet or do try to redirect a browser to a server on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by

- Creating an init script to enforce our iptables rule set
- Creating a set of iptables rules that could be put in place on a Linux gateway

To have a detailed info on how to do this. Please follow the link given below

http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/12/setup-linux-gateway-using-iptables/